# How does blocking increase sos_scheduler_yield wait?

Tags: sql-server, tempdb, blocking, wait-types

What is the correlation between blocking and CPU? Because I am reaching the conclusion that the blocking is causing my `sos_scheduler_yield` wait type to increase, but I would like to understand the reasoning, i.e. why is blocking (in particular waiting for `LCK_M_SCH_S`) causing high `sos_scheduler_yield` wait type.

Is it the background tasks? Also, the blocking is in tempdb. I see a python connection sleeping with statement `drop table #temp` and other sessions are blocked, even some of my DMV queries get blocked by this.

I think the developer has `drop if exists` to be able to rerun the code in the same session (at least I always do that). It is ad hoc queries in a session in SSMS.

I first would like to confirm that my conclusion seems reasonable and then understand the connection.

I am not convinced from the answer below. If queries time-out because of the blocking and then restart, it seems reasonable that `sos_scheduler_yield` wait type goes up.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no direct relationship.  sos_scheduler_yield generally indicates CPU is a bottleneck, as sessions yielding the worker (cpu) are having to wait to get scheduled on a worker again.

Blocking on LCK_M_SCH_S means that a session is performing DDL and causing other sessions to wait.

The sessions performing DDL may *also* be driving high CPU utilization. For example if you're rebuilding an index offline you would hold an Sch-M lock while performing a long-running CPU-intensive operation.